# word frequency + visualization + python

Tags: python

Here is my Code:

```
from urllib import request
from collections import Counter
from nltk import word_tokenize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from yellowbrick.text import DispersionPlot
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import numpy as np

URL = 'http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/24681/pg24681.txt'

RESPONSE = request.urlopen(URL)
RAW = RESPONSE.read().decode('utf8')

for char in '-.,\n;:?=)(/&%$§"!)12345678':
    RAW = RAW.replace(char, ' ')

type(RAW)
print('\n')
len(RAW)

TOKENS = word_tokenize(RAW)

print(type(TOKENS))
X = print(len(TOKENS))
print(TOKENS[:X])

print('\n')

C = Counter(TOKENS)
print(C.most_common(100))
```

**My first question:**

can you show me a way how I can get a `scatter plot` out of it, showing simply the frequency of words in the text. The same with an `n-gram frequency distribution plot`. it should only visualize word frequencies. appearance of the visualization itself is not important. The plot should not be saved anywhere. After executing the code, plot should immediately appear. As an error it shows me always something connected to this part of code:

```
 C = Counter(TOKENS)
 print(C.most_common(100))
```

**And I got a second question:**

if I create a histogram like that, stopwords do not work, why? Means the Output shows first of all "the", "of", "a" and so on.  Here the Code:

```
vocab_labels, vocab_values = zip(*Counter(C).items())

sorted_values = sorted(vocab_values)[::-1]
sorted_labels = [x for (y,x) in sorted(zip(vocab_values,vocab_labels))][::-1]
indexes = np.arange(len(sorted_labels[:10]))
width = 1

plt.bar(indexes, sorted_values[:10]) 
plt.xticks(indexes + width * 0.1, sorted_labels[:10])
plt.show()
```

Thanks for helping, if you have any questions inform me. I tried already many things. They did not worked out very well.

Thanks for helping

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be about bitcoin at all

Comment: What is this question even doing here?  Was this supposed to be posted on Stack Overflow or perhaps the Cross-Validated Stack Exchange?

Comment: @StatsStudent. Now that it's been migrated, I have to say, nothing is any clearer.

Comment: Sorry, absolutely right it was supposed to post on stackoverflow. Thank your for migrating the post.